# How to compose react-hook-form into component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use `react-hook-form` (https://react-hook-form.com/) first time.
I don't know how to compose them into react components with redux.

```
import React from 'react'
import useForm from 'react-hook-form'

export default function SampleForm() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm()
    const onSubmit = data => { console.log(data) }

    console.log(watch('example')) // watch input value by passing the name of it

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <input name="example" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />
            <input name="exampleRequired" ref={register({ required: true })} />
            {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    );
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import userForm from 'react-hook-form';
import SampleForm from "./SampleForm";

class Sample extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SampleForm />
        );
    }
}

export default connect()(Sample);
```

Does anyone help me?

Comment: Calling a function inside a JSX element without curly brackets isn'y valid and you made a typo when importing the library. Look at my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Pro tip:** Most well-supported libraries have an example directory in their Github repo. When I struggle with implementing a library I haven't used before, I just look at one of the [examples](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/tree/master/examples).

Like this awesome [example](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/examples/basic.tsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';

function SampleForm() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input name="firstName" placeholder="bill" ref={register} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input name="lastName" placeholder="luo" ref={register} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input name="email" placeholder="bluebill1049@hotmail.com" type="email" ref={register} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

class Sample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <SampleForm />;
  }
}

export default connect()(Sample);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Sample />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you. My question might out of question, however I would like to use `react-hook-form` inside the Component class.

Comment: One more question. If I would like to dispatch action from the `SampleForm`, how should I get parents `props.dispatch`?

Comment: Hmm, I've actually never really used Redux. Never had the need for it and it seems like an overkill. But I guess if you pass it as a prop to the SampleForm: `<SampleForm dispatch={this.props.dispatch} />` and then destructure it inside the SampleFrom like this: `function SampleForm({ dispatch }) {...`, then you can just call this Redux function where you want!

Comment: `react-redux` provides hooks api, you can call `useDispatch` to get access to dispatch from redux provider.